# How to ensure threads are blocked?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I have a multi threaded C benchmark that can be depicted as following:

```
Thread 1   Thread 2   Thread 3       Control thread

while(1)   while(1)    while(1)       while(1)
   |          |          |             
   |          |          |                |             
   |          |          |            every one second: 
   |          |          |               wait for other threads to be blocked
   |          |          |               do something with S values
   |          |          |                |             
   |          |          |                |             
 write S1    write S2   write S3          |
   |          |          |                |          
   |          |          |                |
 barrier     barrier   barrier         barrier
```

My problem concerns the `wait for other threads to be blocked` statement in the diagram above. For now I came to the following solution to implement it:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define NB_THREADS 11

pthread_barrier_t b;
uint8_t blocked_flags[NB_THREADS] = {0};
pthread_mutex_t blocked_flags_mutexes[NB_THREADS];
uint64_t states[NB_THREADS] = {0};

uint64_t time_diff_get(struct timespec *start, struct timespec *end) {
  uint64_t end_ns = end->tv_sec * 1E9 + end->tv_nsec;
  uint64_t start_ns = start->tv_sec * 1E9 + start->tv_nsec;
  uint64_t res = end_ns - start_ns;
  return res;
}

static void *worker_thread(void *arg) {
  uint8_t id = *((uint8_t *)arg);
  int a =  0;
  while(1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      a++;
    }
    states[id]++;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[id]);
    blocked_flags[id] = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[id]);
    pthread_barrier_wait(&b);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[id]);
    blocked_flags[id] = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[id]);
  }
  printf ("a = %d\n", a);
  return NULL;
}

static void *control_thread() {

  struct timespec last_time;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &last_time);

  while(1) {

    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time);
    if (time_diff_get(&last_time, &time) >= 1E9) {

      // Wait for all threads to be blocked
      for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
        while (1) {
          pthread_mutex_lock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[i]);
          if (blocked_flags[i] == 1) {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[i]);
            break;
          }
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[i]);
        }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[i]);
        if (blocked_flags[i] == 0) {
          printf("How could I avoid to be there ??\n");
          exit(-1);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[i]);
      }

      // Do some intersting stuff here with states array
      // .....
      // .....

      // Save last time
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &last_time);
    }

    pthread_barrier_wait(&b);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main() {

  // Init barrier
  pthread_barrier_init(&b, NULL, NB_THREADS + 1);

  // Create worker threads
  pthread_t threads[NB_THREADS];
  uint8_t ids[NB_THREADS];
  for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
    ids[i] = i;
    pthread_mutex_init(&blocked_flags_mutexes[i], NULL);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    cpu_set_t cpu_set;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpu_set);
    CPU_SET(i + 1, &cpu_set);
    pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu_set);
    pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, worker_thread, &ids[i]);
  }

  // Create control thread
  pthread_t ctrl_thread;
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  cpu_set_t cpu_set;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpu_set);
  CPU_SET(0, &cpu_set);
  pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(&attr, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpu_set);
  pthread_create(&ctrl_thread, &attr, control_thread, NULL);

  // Join on worker threads
  for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But running this benchmark compiled with `gcc -O0` on a 12 cores Intel plateform clearly shows me that I have a "race" problem somewhere because the process always exit after few seconds with the message. How can I solve this ?

Note: following other questions I thought to use a custom barrier, but I need to keep using pthread_barrier and not barrier re implemented on top of mutex and cond variables.

Comment: You should really check the return values of the functions you call so you know whether they succeeded or not.

Comment: One counting semaphore would probably work better than multiple mutexes.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code has an obvious race condition.** When your threads are unblocked by the barrier wait, then they reset the flag to zero. Before they do this, their flag is still 1 for some time. The control thread can observe this stale value of 1, and think that the corresponding thread has already prepared to block, when in fact that thread is only just about to clear the flag, having just come out of the barrier wait:

```
// worker thread
pthread_barrier_wait(&b);
// No longer blocked, but blocked_flags[id] is still 1.
// At this point, the control thread grabs the mutex, and observes the 1 value
// The mistake is thinking that 1 means "I'm about to block"; it actually
// means, "I'm either about to block on the barrier, or have just finished".
pthread_mutex_lock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[id]);
blocked_flags[id] = 0;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&blocked_flags_mutexes[id]);
```

This race condition is enough to sometimes fool the control thread that everyone is blocked, and thus pass through its first loop. Then it falls into the second loop where it finds that not all flags are zero.

The essence of your problem is that you have some repeated, cyclic parallel processing done by a herd of threads, controlled by a barrier. However, you are using only a single barrier wait in the cycle, which means the cycle has only a single phase.  However, semantically, your cycle is divided into two phases: threads blocked and unblocked.  The mechanism you have built to distinguish these phases is not thread safe; and the obvious solution is to just use the barrier again to split the cycle into more phases.

POSIX barriers have the "serial thread" feature: one of the waiting threads is informed that it is special. This lets you implement special phases in which only the serial thread performs some important action and the other threads can do something else, like call the barrier wait to skip to the next phase. That should eliminate the need to implement hacks, like flags by means of which one thread tries to guess when the other threads have become quiescent.

NOTE: you cannot choose which thread is the serial thread in a POSIX barrier wait, so you cannot have a dedicated control thread just for that action. Instead of N+1 threads you just use N threads. They all do the same thing, and when they reach the barrier; any one of them can be told that it is the serial thread. Based on that, the serial thread executes some alternative code compared to the others.

So, diagram time:

```
while(1)   while(1)    while(1)       
   |          |          |             
   |          |          |          
   |          |          | 
   |          |          |   <---- WRITE PHASE  
   |          |          |  
   |          |          |             
   |          |          |                 
 write S1    write S2   write S3
   |          |          |           
   |          |          |      
 barrier     barrier   barrier 
   |          |          |        
   |          |          |     <--- CHECK PHASE
   |          |          |           
   |          |     serial thread!   
   |          |          |           
   |          |       next second?-- YES -> do something with S values!
   |          |          |  NO        |
   |          |          |            |
   |          |          +------------+ 
   |          |          | 
 barrier     barrier   barrier
   |          |          | 
   |          |          | 

back to top, next WRITE PHASE.
```

Here, in the `CHECK PHASE`, the serial thread (could be any one of the N threads) performs a check: has the time transitioned into the next second since the last time we transitioned into the next second? If so, it does something with the S values.

**The barrier ensures that the other threads are not touching the values in the `CHECK_PHASE` so the serial thread needs no mutex to work with the S values!**  You've paid for this synchronization already with the extra barrier call in each loop.

You could have an extra thread which provides a time base: its job is to sleep until the next second arrives, and then increment a counter. The serial thread only has to check that this counter has incremented (relative to its old value, stored in another variable). Then do the action and update the old counter to match the new. This way, you don't have to make a call to the operating system to get the current time in the main processing loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping a flag for each worker-thread, you could mutex-protect a single counter and each worker-thread could increment this counter when about to block and decrement it after the barrier releases it.  That would save you from waiting for the first thread to be blocked, then the second thread, then the third, etc.

I don't see where your control-thread exits (other than in the unexpected condition) and the main thread doesn't seem to wait for it.

Perhaps you'd also like to create your control-thread before the worker-threads.

Perhaps you'd also like to synchronize the worker-threads and the control-thread by having them wait on the barrier before being released and beginning their actual work!

Answer (score 0):

I think wht happens could be this:

- in the first execution of `while(1)` in control_thread(), `time_diff_get(&last_time, &time)` returns a value < 1E9, so the thread runs directly into the barrier
- now all working threads will run into the barrier eventually
- after this has happened, `control_thread()` executes it's loop for the second time and immediately checks for `blocked_flags[i]`
- if this happens for at least one thread before that thread has reset it's flag, you will have the behaviour you have expected.

Sorry I can't provide a solution at the moment, but if I'm right understanding the problem is a good start for a solution.